# Access json request from python in python AWS lambda function

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, python-requests, aws-api-gateway

I have an API in the AWS API gateway, connected to an AWS Lambda function in python, using lambda proxy integration. On my local computer, I am testing this API in python. I want to send a dictionary to the api and have the api return me a function of the elements in the dictionary.

The python code I use to test is:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://p68yzl6gu6.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/helloworld"

headers = {'data': [0,1]}

response = requests.post(url, json=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Since I cannot send a list through the header argument of requests.post I thought I'd use json. When I try this, I get a {"message": "Internal server error"}. This is my AWS lambda function (python):

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': event['data']
    }
```

Looking at the logs, 'data' is not a key of event. How do I access the list in the AWS Lambda function? How do I find out what the event dictionary looks like when I test this? Looking forward I want to send a large dict containing dicts and lists. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Try showing event keys by calling event.keys() inside the lambda_handler method and see what pops up.

Comment: Where exactly would I do that? Where it says event['data']? If I do that and call my python function I still get an internal server error which doesn't really help..

Comment: above the return statement

Comment: Thanks, if I do that, how/where would I see the output of that line?

Comment: I'm finding there are quite a few essential assumptions that are largely undocumented about using AWS Lambda. Does AWS convert your response to JSON or not, possibly controlled by a flag in the AWS configuration, how are stderr stdout handled, what is the default logging set up, etc. I like that "where would I see the output" question - exactly!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    body = json.loads(event['body'])
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(body['data'])
    }
```

Comment: Try again, I added a json.dumps @WilliamSteenbergen

Comment: @WilliamSteenbergen try again

Comment: yes that works, thanks so much! the json.loads does it.

Comment: @WilliamSteenbergen no prob